# Considering the first element as the pivot,why won't index i exceed the bound of array?

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

Inside the two while loops of **partition** method, why it seems that whether index i exceed the bound of array is not being considered from first sight?[This is the right code from Big Java, I've tested already, just the index stuff confuses me]

```
public void sort(int from, int to)
   {
      if (from >= to) return;
      int p = partition(from, to);
      sort(from, p);
      sort(p + 1, to);
   }

   private int partition(int from, int to)
   {
      int pivot = a[from];
      int i = from - 1;
      int j = to + 1;
      while (i < j)
      {
         i++; while (a[i] < pivot) i++;//here
         j--; while (a[j] > pivot) j--;//here
         if (i < j) swap(i, j); 
      }
      return j;
   }
```

Comment: Who said we don't care? Call `sort` with `from` or `to` that exceed the limits and you will get an exception. I encourage you to add a boundary validation.

Comment: In the lines where you put `//here` try to add a boundary validation to avoid the `out of bounds exception`.  If `a[i]` never is `< pivot` or `a[j]` never is `> pivot` with the code you have, you will receive an `out of bounds exception`.

Comment: This is the right code, I've copied it and tested already

Answer (score 1):

Since the pivot is chosen from the same array and due to how the logic of the algorithm is implemented you never need to check for the indices to go out of bounds. At some point of the execution the conditions must turn true.

The correctness of the algorithm can be proved using loop invariants.

```
1. private int partition(int from, int to)
2. {
3.    int pivot = a[from];
4.    int i = from - 1;
5.    int j = to + 1;
6.    while (i < j)
7.    {
8.        i++; 
9.        // at least one of a[i]...a[to] is greater than or equal to pivot 
10.       while (a[i] < pivot) i++;
11.       j--; 
12.       // at least one of a[from]...a[j] is less than or equal to pivot
13.       while (a[j] > pivot) j--;//here
14.       if (i < j) swap(i, j);
15.       // if i < j then at least one of a[i + 1]...a[to] is greater than or equal to pivot
16.       // if i < j then at least one of a[from]...a[j - 1] is less than or equal to pivot
17.   }
18.   return j;
19. }
```

Lines 9 and 12 (and 15, 16) contain the invariants that hold true for every iteration of the loop 6 to 17. From these invariants it is clear that `i` and `j` indices can never go out of array bounds.

We can prove only the invariant on line 9, the invariant on line 12 can be proved analogously.

For the 1st iteration it is true because the pivot is chosen as `a[from]` and `i = from`.

At the end of every iteration (including the 1st iteration) we move the element at position `i` that is greater than or equal to pivot to position `j`. Because `i < j` then the invariant on line 15 holds true. On the next iteration after incrementing `i` on line 8 the invariant 9 becomes valid which follows directly from the invariant 15. By induction we can conclude that the invariant 9 is valid on every iteration of the loop 6 to 17.

If we chose pivot as last element of array i.e. a[to] the invariants would still hold true. However we would need to change the flow in the sort method.

```
sort(from, p == to ? p - 1 : p);
sort(p + 1, to);
```

instead of

```
sort(from, p);
sort(p + 1, to);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's true, both the increase of i and decrease of j will never pass the pivot, it's like the pivot stop the behavior of beyond the bound in advance. But can you explain more about the logic of the algorithm, please? When it comes to logic, you mean the loop invariants? I was taught that the invariants works as a guide when you coding, but I still find it is difficult in coding upon the invariants.

Comment: @xiasheng you are right, we can use loop invariants to prove the correctness of the algorithm. I updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

In your main `partition` loop you can see that `i` and `j` start at each end of the array and work towards the `pivot` while the element at that location is `<` or `>` the pivot. They both must stop at the pivot chosen so they will never escape the array.

```
int[] a;

private void sort() {
    sort(0, a.length - 1);
}

public void sort(int from, int to) {
    if (from >= to) {
        return;
    }
    int p = partition(from, to);
    sort(from, p);
    sort(p + 1, to);
}

private int partition(int from, int to) {
    int pivot = a[from];
    int i = from - 1;
    int j = to + 1;
    while (i < j) {
        i++;
        while (a[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        j--;
        while (a[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            swap(i, j);
        }
    }
    return j;
}

private void swap(int i, int j) {
    int t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    a = new int[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    sort();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Note that using `numbers[low]` as the pivot merely degrades performance - the algorithm still sorts the array correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the right code, it is from a book called Big Java, I've tested it already

Comment: @fabian - Sorry - I should have checked that.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration both indices cannot pass the `pivot` element, since `i < pivotIndex < j`. Therefore you cannot pass the bounds in the first iteration (provided indices are in valid range and `from <= to`; also indices are within range after the increment/decrement statements before the loops).

In all iterations after the first the indices cannot become smaller than `from` or larger than `to`, since `i < j` and the `swap`-call in last loop iteration placed an element that makes the respective loop conditions `false` at indices `i` and `j` respectively: For the element at position `j` `a[j] > pivot` was false, but that element was moved to position `i < j` and for the element at position `i` `a[i] < pivot` was false, but that element was moved to position `j > i`.

Comment: also, how to change the code if we choose the last element as the pivot?